# Disable notification of apps

Tags: android, android-notifications

Whenever there is a notification in android there is LED blink until we see that notification.Can I disable notification (LED blinking) for the android apps when my service is running in the background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default your notifications are created with option:
     .setDefaults((Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
which includes all options including DEFAULT_LIGHTS if you don't want lights to be shown just set the options you want. You can view which settings are available here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html
About the while service is running part just change options for your notification in for example  onStartCommand() for your service and change them back to default in onDestroy().

Comment: I want stop led blinking for any app in the device. Until my service is running no led will blink whatsoever.

Comment: I thought you only wanted to stop notifications(led part) in your app while service is running. Stopping them on the system part would be much more difficult probably even ROM dependant. Only pointer I could give you in that regard would be that your app will have to be added to device administrators to be able to do this.

Answer (score -1):

yes you can.  Go to settings > System >> Notification light>> check use custom values.

Then you will get a +/plus button. 
At the bottom of your screen.

You can select your application for which you don't want the notification lights to blink :)

And select custom color for that app  that is select black color done

No more blinks ;)

Tried it on 4.2.2  working

here is a  screenshot http://www.mediafire.com/?lk9ba5f0tkdb1vq

Comment: he has not mentioned if it is a custom or stock, this holds for custom roms

Comment: I don't want to do this manually but through my app. Moreover I want to prevent LED blinking for any app in the device (including red glow while battery charging).